# Content in Documentation Beta

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

Is it OK to quote definition of terms from other sites by explicitly quoting source site?

Example:

The definition of Decorator from wikipedia:

DECORATOR is a design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class

UML diagram:

Diagram link from external site

Etc...

I have my own code examples to add to the documentation but definitions and use cases can be quoted from other sites in Remarks section?

It would be great if Do's and Don't are published regarding documentation.

Answer (score 4):

**Try to avoid it.** If a quote makes up some small part of a topic, and you indicate it's source, fine - but don't populate descriptions and remarks entirely with quotes. Quite honestly, if you can't think of anything to write, there's a good chance you don't need to write anything.

#### See also and especially: [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

...which reads in part,

> Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. And always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link to it.